# Actualizar valores al ejecutar onclick

Tags: jquery, ajax

Necesito cambiar el estado de un boton al ejecutar un click tanto en el propio botón como en BBDD.
El botón puede contener el texto "Active" o "Inactive" por lo que según su estado, al hacer click tendrá que cambiar a su valor contrario
La part de php la tengo realizada, pero con js no tengo mucho conocimiento.
Añado el código que tengo actualmente

Inserción del botón dinamicamete:

```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $status = $row['register_status'];
        if ($status == "Active") {
            //$register_status = '<button class="btn btn-success disabled">Enable</button>';
            $register_status = '<button class="btn btn-success btn_status" id="btn_status" data-status="Active">Active</button>';
        }
        else {
            //$register_status = '<button class="btn btn-warning disabled">Disable</button>';
            $register_status = '<button class="btn btn-warning btn_status" id="btn_status" data-status="Inactive">Inactive</button>';
        }

        $data .= '<tr>
                        <td width="1%"><mark>#'.$row['id'].'</mark></td>
                        <td>'.$row['first_name'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['last_name'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
                        <td width="1%">'.$register_status.'</td>
                        <td width="1%">
                                <div class="dropdown">
```

**updateStatus.php**

```
include("db_connection.php");
if(isset($_POST))
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $register_status = $_POST['register_status'];
    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `register_status` = '$register_status'  WHERE `id` = '$id'";
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($db,$query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error());
    }
}
```

Con el siguiente script intento cambiar el texto del botón, pero no lo actualiza y luego queria pasar el fichero ajax/updateStatus.php para la actualización en BBDD

**script.js**

```
$('body').click('#btn_status', function(event){
if(button.data('status') == 'Active'){
        alert("button is clicked");
      }else if(button.data('status') == 'Inactive'){
        alert("button is clicked");
      }
});
```

Los diferentes botones que hay son estos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien puede ayudar con este código?

Comment: Debes utilizar ajax para realizar dicha petición y de esta manera según la respuesta de la BD cambias el valor del elemento DOM que deseas. De la forma en que estas realizando esto, no manejas el que pueda existir un eventual error al updatear la BD

Comment: y para cambiar el valor del texto que tiene el boton?

Comment: Bastaría con un `$('#btn').text('newText')`

Comment: He actualizado el post con la generación dinamica del botón puesto que únicamente me cambia el valor del primer botón. Si hago click en otro botón, siempre me modifica el primero y no en el de la posición que hago el onclick

Comment: Pero lo que quieres es que al clickear un botón, este cambie el texto? o que al clickear un botón se cambien todos?

Comment: Que cambie el texto del que hago click. No el de todos porque cada uno tendrá un valor diferente según lo recoja de la BBDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cambiar el valor del texto del boton, bastaría con cambiarle el valor con `[html][1]`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').click('.btn_status', function(e){
  var button = jQuery(e.target);
  if(button.data('status') == 'Active'){
          button.data('status', 'Inactive');
          button.html('Inactive');
        }else if(button.data('status') == 'Inactive'){
          button.data('status', 'Active');
          button.html('Active');
        }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-warning btn_status" data-status="Inactive">Inactive</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning btn_status" data-status="Inactive">Inactive</button>
```

Comment: Los botonos se generan automaticamente según el valor de la BBDD. Al ejecutar el codigo, únicamente me modifica el primer botón, pero todo el resto no funcionan

Comment: Actualice la respuesta, entonces tendrias que hacerlo desde la clase y no desde el ID.

Comment: Actualizado el post con la generación dinamica del botón. El problema es que me actualiza el primer botón siempre. Si hago click en cualquier otro botón, siempre me actualiza el primero.

Comment: pero insistes en hacer esto `$('body').click('#btn_status'` debes cambiarlo por `$('body').click('.btn_status'` como en el ejemplo

Comment: Osea que en ves de poner un listener por `#IDdelElemento` se lo das a la `.ClasedelElemento`

Comment: Al parecer lo que el OP quiere es que cambie el texto del botón que clickea, no que se actualicen todos los textos clickeando sólo uno... pero la pregunta no es clara =/

Comment: Eso es. Que cambien el botón que haga click. No el de todos porque cada uno tendrá un valor diferente según lo recoja de la BBDD.

Comment: @jolsalazar Aclarado! Te dejo la respuesta a ti =)

Comment: Ok, de todas maneras el codigo ya lo hace, ejecuta el codigo que acabo de actualizar, donde verás que se modifica el texto y valor del boton seleccionado.

Comment: veo que tu código lo cambia, pero en el mio no... Yo creo que se pierde algo al generarse dinamicamente y por eso siempre se actualiza unicamente el primero botón. He actualizado con una imagen de los diferentes botonos. en cualquiera que hago un click, siempre me cambia el valor al primero

Comment: Si tu codigo actual, es el que actualizaste en la pregunta, sigues dandole listener a un solo boton al utilizar el ID y no la Clase en el codigo de javascript

Comment: Además de que te dará error, por que no estas usando lo que te comparti.

Comment: @jolsalazar me funciono! tenia puesto el "id" y al quitarlo ya funciona. Gracias!